# Plist not changing value [swift]

Tags: swift, plist

I wanted to implement the in-app version for my app, but I don't understand why is not working? The output showing i was added successfully, but when i open the pList file from my Xcode, its not changing? Why is it? Here is my code:

```
func version(){

    let urlString = jocomAPIKey + "/feed/version"
    let CFBundleShortVersionKey = "CFBundleVersion"

    //First get the nsObject by defining as an optional anyObject
    let nsObject: AnyObject? = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleVersion"]
    let version = nsObject as! String
    print("app version: \(version)")


    Alamofire.request(.POST, urlString , parameters: ["os" : "iphone"])

        .responseData { response in

            let versionXML = SWXMLHash.parse(response.data!)
            let versionString = (versionXML["rss"]["channel"]["item"]["version"].element?.text)
            print("version string: \(versionString)")

            if let plist = Plist(name: "Info") {

                let dict = plist.getMutablePlistFile()!
                dict[CFBundleShortVersionKey] = versionString
                //3
                do {
                    try plist.addValuesToPlistFile(dict)
                    print("added")
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                //4
                print(plist.getValuesInPlistFile())
            } else {
                print("Unable to get Plist")
            }


        }


}
```

[image: plist]

Comment: You cannot write into info.plist (nor into any other file in the application bundle) at runtime.

Comment: @vadian but i wanted to implement my own api version to force user update everytime, how do i do it? pls guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't update your (Bundle plist) at run-time. If you want use then you just make one `copy` on your `Document Directory` then you can perform any `operation`.

[Write and Read a plist in swift with simple data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498400/write-and-read-a-plist-in-swift-with-simple-data)

Comment: but i wanted to implement my own api version to force user update everytime, how do i do it? pls guide me

Comment: Once you copy bundle plis on document directory then you can check or update your api version.

Comment: you mean copy the plist file into a new plist file? then only i can read and write the plist?

Comment: Yes, file path must be application document directory and access all time document directory plist.

Comment: If you dont know how to copy then just review this answer :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100262/save-data-to-plist-file-in-swift

Comment: Are you satisfied with answer don't forgot to accept. Happy coding.

Comment: Is it i wont be able to see the value that i added inside the plist? I only able to retrieve it from log

Comment: Yes you can also `read and wright value` from plist just print document directory file then see that physically plist file file.

Comment: If you dont know how to read plist then review this answer :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498400/write-and-read-a-plist-in-swift-with-simple-data

Comment: Thanks. How do i prompt a alertview to force user to update? if new version is up

Comment: Just review this link for that :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221436/can-i-force-an-iphone-user-to-upgrade-an-application

Answer (score 1):

Apple not allow to update info.plist update at runtime in app.