# What to change for this StringByAppendingPathComponent

Tags: swift2

My Swift code is not working after converting to Swift2.2.
My code :

Swift 1.0 code:

```
Class func getPath(filename:  String ) -> String {
return NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask,true)[0].stringByAppendingComponent(filename)
}
```

error : Use URLByAppendingPathComponent On NSURL instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stringByAppendingPathComponent is unavailable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501627/stringbyappendingpathcomponent-is-unavailable)

Comment: P.s. that line is way too long. Break it down.

Comment: I have no idea. This is what happened to my code. I will take a look at your suggested link.

Comment: Can you help me? That is my static method, I don't know how to break it down as you suggested. I need this method the way it is.

Comment: error : Use URLByAppendingPathComponent On NSURL instead.

Comment: Read the provided link. There's a complete answer over there - don't just skim it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Class func getPath(filename:  String ) -> String {
    let basePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    let baseURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: basePath)
    let fullURL = baseURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
    return fullURL.path!
}
```

Comment: Error  on the return statement: Value of Type 'NSURL' has no member  'StringByAppendingComponent

Comment: Oops, should be URLByAppendingPathComponent

Comment: You should probably be using NSURL rather than Strings.

Answer (score 2):

Use the URL related API and the modern way to get the documents directory:

In Swift 2 class functions are marked with `static`

```
static func getPath(filename:  String ) -> String {
  // try! is safe
  let documentDirectory = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory,
                                             inDomain: .UserDomainMask,
                                             appropriateForURL: nil,
                                             create: true)
  return documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(filename).path!
}
```

or completely URL based:

```
static func getURL(filename:  String ) -> NSURL {
   let documentDirectory = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory,
                                           inDomain: .UserDomainMask,
                                           appropriateForURL: nil,
                                           create: true)
   return documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
}
```

Comment: I will try and get back here

Comment: Apple encourages the developers to use URL based API as much as possible.