# How to get path to a subfolder in main bundle?

Tags: ios, swift3, nsbundle

I have a project which I am migrating from Obj-C to Swift 3.0 (and I am quite a noob in Swift).

How do I translate this line?

```
NSString *folder = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfolder"];
```

I managed to get resource path:

```
let resoursePath = Bundle.main.resoursePath;
```

But how do I get path to a subfolder named "myfolder"?
I need to get a path the subfolder, not path to the files inside it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Swift-3 make `URL`, and call `appendingPathComponent`:

```
let resourcePath = Bundle.main.resourcePath
let subdir = URL(fileURLWithPath:resourcePath!).appendingPathComponent("sub").path
```

or simply

```
let subdir = Bundle.main.resourceURL!.appendingPathComponent("sub").path
```

(thanks, [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r)!)

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39874091/335858) on information on `stringByAppendingPathComponent` method in Swift.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the comment!

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
let folderURL = resourceURL(to: "myfolder")

func resourceURL(to path: String) -> URL? {
    return URL(string: path, relativeTo: Bundle.main.resourceURL)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to get listing of the bundle subdirectory and get resources only of the specific type:

```
Bundle.main.paths(forResourcesOfType: type, inDirectory: folder)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5.0

**Swift 5**:

Caveat: Assumes that your folder is actually in the bundle; (that you added the folder to the project via 'Add Folder Reference', not by the 'Add Groups' option).

```
bundle.main.path(forResource: "myfolder", ofType: nil)
```

**Objective-C**: (your example)

```
NSString *folder = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfolder"];
```

**Other Swift ways**:

As a URL (Apple's preferred method, the `:URL?` is only included here to clarify that this does not produce a string):

```
let folderURL:URL? = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myfolder", withExtension: nil)
```

Appending as a string:

```
let folder = Bundle.main.resourcePath?.appending("/myfolder")
// or
let y = Bundle.main.resourcePath?.appending("/").appending("myfolder")
```

The following literal translation fails, as appendingPathComponent is no longer available in the Swift `String` type which is slightly different from `NSString`:

```
let folder = Bundle.main.resourcePath?.appendingPathComponent("myfolder")
```