# How to get the plist file lists in project

Tags: arrays, swift, plist

I have a few data files like

```
AAA.plist
BBB.plist
CCC.plist
```

I would like to get the list of these plist file.
If I know the file name in advance,
I can get the file like this.

```
 let path : String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "AAA", ofType: "plist")!
 var qplist = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)
```

However I want to get the plist file list in case of not knowing the file name in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`urls(forResourcesWithExtension:subdirectory:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle/1407424-urls) for that.

```
if let urls = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "plist", subdirectory: nil) {

     print(urls)
}
//Set subdirectory with specific name instead of nil if files inside some directory.
```

You can also use [`paths(forResourcesOfType:inDirectory:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle/1413058-paths) to get array of paths.

Comment: FYI - Note that the files will only be in a subdirectory if the folder in your Xcode project is blue and not yellow.

Comment: Yes, whitebear @rmaddy is correct set `subdirectory` only if folder color is blue not yellow.

Comment: Thanks Nirav D and thanks rmaddy for your advice. Xcode group/folder system is quite confusing to me....

Comment: @whitebear Welcome mate :)

Comment: It works with subdirectory, however is it possible to use group instead of subdirectory??? I would like to pick the plist files under a certain group

Comment: @whitebear group will not create directory it will just use to manage view in Xcode if you check in location there is no directory with that group name, So you need to add the sub directory name not the group name also if it is with main project then `nil` will also works

Comment: @Nirav D I see.... it I just wonder why group/folder system is very complex and which I should use. And If I use subdirectory system here, I need to access each files another place, I also check this article you edit and learning, thank you very much  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692737/how-to-get-path-to-a-subfolder-in-main-bundle

Answer (score 0):

Use the enumerator from FileManager:

```
let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath
let man = FileManager.default

for file in man.enumerator(atPath: path!)! {
    print(file)
}
```

Comment: Look at all of those crash operators.

Comment: Yeah yeah yeah, didn't include my normal disclaimer about needing nil protection :)

Comment: `Bundle.urls(forResources...)` is a better choice anyway.