# Adding Variable in plist string

Tags: ios, swift, variables, plist

I would like to add a variable in plist string. It is possible to do so?

e.g. in item 0 in an array. The string is "Today is XXXXX"
In my swift file, I was able to load the plist and the String. But how can I insert my variable into that plist string? How should I put in my plist and what to code in my swift file?

Thanks

Comment: Hope this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100262/save-data-to-plist-file-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDict: NSDictionary?
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Config", ofType: "plist") {
    myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
}
if let dict = myDict {
    // Use your dict here
}
```