# Write and read file with list NSDictonary swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a list of NSDictionary, and i want to save it in a file. I can save it in text file but i can't read it to [NSDictionary]

```
var text : [NSDictionary] = []
```

save file

```
let json = JSONSerializer.toJson(text)
try json.write(to: path, atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

This is my list NSDictionary

```
[{ change = true; name = data1; },{ change = true; name = data2; }]
```

Comment: you have only problem with reading data from text file right ?

Comment: Please post the code you use to read the file.

Comment: i update this in answers

Comment: save dictionary to plist http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100262/save-data-to-plist-file-in-swift/40318366#40318366

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
        let text2 = try NSString(contentsOfURL: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) // path give your file path
        print(text2)
    }
    catch {/* error handling here */}
}
```

**Try this and tell is your problem solve or not .**

Answer (score 0):

update code read file

```
let text2 = try String(contentsOf: path!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                    print(text2)
                    arrayFile = try JSONSerializer.toArray(text2) as! [NSDictionary]
                    print(arrayFile)
```

and print(text2)

```
{[{ 
change = true;
name = data1;
},{
change = true;
name = data2;
}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user plist for dictionary of data. Here is how we write data to plist file.

```
var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
var path = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("data.plist")
var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
if (!(fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path)))
{
    var bundle : NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("data", ofType: "plist")
    fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundle, toPath: path, error:nil)
}
data.setObject(object, forKey: "object")
data.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
```

To read data from plist file,

```
var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
var path = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("data.plist")
let save = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
```

Comment: @Humyl Share your data so that we can parse it.

Comment: i paste it in my commet