# How do I Generate a Text Message to a Predefined Phone Number in iOS 10?

Tags: ios

Let's say I have the user of my app define a phone number in a setup step of my program, saved in the plist as a number with the key "PhoneNum". Now lets say that I want to have a button in the program which, when pressed, generates a text message that says "Hi! How are you today?" to the phone number saved under "PhoneNum". Is it possible to have this message auto-send without confirmation from the user? If so, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25172186/2894160 I think it can help you

Comment: Your question is way to boards and looks like a code request, which is frowned up and will get your question down voted. You should split up your question and post code where you have tried to solve the issue yourself. Also send an text message without the user interactie will not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, if you pay for an SMS-sending service. Type “sms sending api” into your favorite search engine.

If you want to send a message through the user's own iMessages or cell phone account, then you cannot do it without confirmation. [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)