# Why can't I save data in plist file with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, plist

** the readData.plist is:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>currentChapter</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>currentLine</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>bookname</key>
    <string>ExcelBible</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

** The following is code:**

```
        let Chapter = currentChapter
        let Line = currentLine
        let name = bookname

        let dict:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()



        dict.setObject("1", forKey: "currentChapter" as NSCopying)
        dict.setObject("1", forKey: "currentLine" as NSCopying)
        dict.setObject("WordBible", forKey: "bookname" as NSCopying)

        //I also use dict[0] = "1", and setValue() method both of them are not work

        let plistPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "readData", ofType: "plist")

        dict.write(toFile: plistPath!, atomically: true)
```

> Blockquote
>      I also use FileManager and several examples here to save data, some display "Successfully write", but the file does't change.
>
> Blockquote

---

**I am an iOS developer since Feb 12, 2020**

Comment: I read from .plist is no problem.

Comment: You cannot write into the application bundle. It's read-only. And `NSCoding` is discouraged in Swift. Use `PropertyListEncoder` And never use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift. All native types are mutable by default as `var`iable. And please conform to the naming convention and name variables and methods with starting lowercase letter.

Comment: Thank your advice of PropertyListEncoder and code writing method.

I changed my code, but it still does't work
```

let currentChapter = "10"
let currentLine = "10"
let nameOfBook = "WordBible"

let readData = [currentChapter, currentLine, nameOfBook]
//

let dataFilePaths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                             in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("gameSave.plist")

let data = try PropertyListEncoder().encode(readData)

try? data.write(to: dataFilePaths, options: Data.WritingOptions.atomic)

```

Comment: You have to create a struct with the 3 properties `currentChapter`, `currentLine` and `nameOfBook` and encode this to get a property list with the corresponding keys.

Comment: Could you tell me why I have to use a struct?

but finally, I have to execute the specific function.

Comment: Because it's more convenient, more efficient and *swiftier*.

Comment: Thank you very much , I got it.

because I am new, so I write code in playground, then move to project use class or struct, but now my task to solve that question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the file is not in a writable location, so you should create it in the documents directory. Then, it has to be read from the documents directory.

Comment: Thank you.

I tried PropertyListEncoder() method under playground and project, it doesn't work.

Comment: That's not what I'm thinking about. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100262/save-data-to-plist-file-in-swift)

Comment: it doesn't work, because I am new to develop. my friend helps me ,but he can not find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

I used the following code, but it does't work too.

> Blockquote

```
let currentChapter = "10"
let currentLine = "10"
let nameOfBook = "WordBible"

let readData = [currentChapter, currentLine, nameOfBook]
//

let dataFilePaths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                             in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("gameSave.plist")

let data = try PropertyListEncoder().encode(readData)

try? data.write(to: dataFilePaths, options: Data.WritingOptions.atomic)
```